# HTML Agility pack - How to get URLs, which start with specific text?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, url, html-agility-pack

The question is in the title, but that is more specific: can I get URL from HTML, which starts with specific text ? may be, is there any case to extract in JQuery-style?

```
$( "a[href^='event_handler']" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-the-box library doesn't support jquery type selectors (those are CSS selectors FYI), but only [XPATH](http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/xpath#w3c_all) or [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/xslt#w3c_all) selectors. Of course there are good people who took their time and added a extension to CSS selector support, see [Add CSS Selector Query Engine onto HTMLAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/28970).

Adding this, you can select your links with the string selector you've already provided yourself.

Answer (score 1):

HTMLAgilityPack is based on using XPath queries, not CSS selectors (which is what you have in your original post).

If you absolutely must use CSS selectors, there is a tool I've used in the past to do this called Fizzler:

https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/

It sits on top of HTMLAgilityPack, so therefore much of the documentation stays the same.

I'd also say your question is a little confusing. Your CSS selector there is selecting something based on it's `href` **starting with** a value, yet you mention you want to select something by it's `text` - which is different. The below is a direct equivlaent of what your original selector is:

```
//a[starts-with(@href, 'event_handler')]
```

However, to match on the actual **text**, not the `href`, then it's:

```
//a[starts-with(text(), 'event_handler')]
```

Comment: You're right, I'm inaccurate in my question. But while googling, I found that original Fizzler is quite old, Fizzler Ex looks younger.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use linq

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li").Where(x => x.FirstChild.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("event_handler")).Select(x => x.FirstChild.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
```